# Mathjax integrals displaying incorrectly

Tags: support, bug, mathjax

On my display the integral display too small and too far down. I see this on every integral displayed on the site.

```
$$ \int f(x) dx $$
```

which is rendered to
$$ \int f(x) dx $$

displays as:

[image]

on my screen. I've not been able to find any mention of this problem in searching. Any idea to to fix it? It's really distracting.

EDIT: This problem persists in both Chrome and Edge.

Comment: This is likely the result of your settings for rendering, not of the browser. I use Chrome (on different platforms, Windows, iOS, and Ubuntu) and do not encounter this problem...

Comment: It looks like one of the fonts might not be coming through properly.  Did you get any warnings in the browser console?  Are you using MathJax from a CDN, or from your own installation?  What version of MathJax are you using?  You might try changing to the SVG renderer if the font problem persists.